# Why is Dirac equation a matrix equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, dirac-equation, spinors, dirac-matrices

According to Wikipedia's [Dirac equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation) article, the Dirac equation can be written in form
$$ i\hbar\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\psi-mc\psi=0, $$
where $\gamma^{\mu}$ are gamma matrices which are $4 \times 4$ matrices. Now is the wavefunction $\psi$ still a scalar like in classical quantum mechanics? If so then isn't this equation a matrix equation meaning that the same scalar function should obey multiple different equations? Why would it be so? Isn't that overdetermination?

Comment: Did you also read the bit where it says $\psi$ is a four component spinor? (That WP page is a mess, it would be fairly easy to do this).

Comment: Well that explains. I tried to see something like that said in that WP page but didn't notice that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, $\psi$ stands for a set of four wavefunctions, forming a Dirac spinor. Both sides of the equation transform as Dirac spinors.

This is not unusual or overdetermined. It's just like how $\mathbf{F} = m \mathbf{a}$ really has "three things" on each side, because it relates two objects that transform as vectors.